# Search in p2p networks

Tags: p2p

In DHT protocol that is used in peer to peer networks, the next node is computed by means of the operation XOR.

Does this mean that the variable is not the route table (DHT), let it be always the same?

I think so, because the minimum value will always have one when calculating the hash XOR.
For example:

```
Table DHT:
156
124
791
123
My hash:
563
Then
156 xor 563 = 687
124 xor 563 = 591
791 xor 563 = 292
123 xor 563 = 584
```

Then then the next node will be 123. Do I understand correctly specifics DHT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me if you mean by "my hash" your node id or the thing you're searching for.  Assuming you are searching for the thing that has hash value 563, it is true that 123 differs from 563 by only 3 bits:

```
584 = 1001001000
292 = 0100100100
591 = 1001001111
687 = 1010101111
```

but so does 791

#### Returning Next

So in terms of distance from 563, selecting 791 or 123 is equal.  DHT search uses XOR as a distance metric, but in both the [BitTorrent DHT BEP](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html), as well as the [original paper it references](http://www.cs.rice.edu/Conferences/IPTPS02/109.pdf), Kademila DHT search maintains a set of concurrent search next nodes of size **k**.  Setting **k** to 1 would be limiting.

> > FIND NODE takes a 160-bit ID as an argument. The recipient of a the RPC returns ⟨IPaddress,UDPport,NodeID⟩ triples for the k nodes it knows about closest to the target ID. These triples can come from a single k-bucket, or they may come from multiple k-buckets if the closest k-bucket is not full. In any case, the RPC recipient must return k items (unless there are fewer than k nodes in all its k-buckets combined, in which case it returns every node it knows about).

Additionally, the search is modified by how responsive the next node is, but assuming everything is equally responsive.  Then yea if **k** = 1, then search results will be { 123 }, if **k** = 2 then { 123, 791 }, if ***k*** = 3, then { 123, 791, 124 }, and if **k** >= 4 then { 123, 791, 124, 156 }.

#### The Search

There is an additional parameter, referred to as **alpha** in the original paper,and also documented in the [libtorrent API](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Settings.html#dht_settings) as **search_branching** that controls how many concurrent queries the search node will have going at any time.

[image: your diagram]

If **alpha** is >=3, then 3 simultaneous queries from the dark red node will be made to each neighbor.  Each node will return the **k** closest neighbors to the search value.  That will be repeated until the destination node is found or no progress is made, in the picture, the destination node was found.

Comment: ,That is used to determine the distance hash node that you want to find, and hashes in the routing table, and not a hash of the current node and heshov routing table ?!

Comment: @ales Use of XOR you mean?  Well both.  It's used to determine how close node-ids are to maintain routing tables, and also for search to progress towards the node that holds the peer information for the data.  Your use of the word "next" made me think search.

Comment: Thank you. can see my previous question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702531/dht-principle-of-operation-choice-of-paths-to-search

Comment: @ales I've updated the answer and included the picture you provided in your previous question for reference.  Nice pic! It would be useful to label the  pic with the node-id of each node as well as the search term.  If you do, ill update the reference too.